# Function to return harmonic mean and average in C

Tags: c

I am writing a function that calculates the harmonic mean and the average of an array of numbers. I know I should probably use pointers to return both output, but I'm not entirely sure how.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double data_analysis(double x[]);

int main() {
    //declare variables
    double x[] = { 3.5, 4.8, -4.1, 2.1, 8.4, 6.4, 2.8 };

    //determine avg and harmonic mean and display results
    data_analysis(x);
}

//function
double data_analysis(double x[]) {
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, sum2 = 0, har_mean = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        sum = sum + x[i];
        sum2 = sum2 + (1.0 / x[i]);
    }
    avg = sum / 7;
    har_mean = 7 * pow(sum2, -1);

    return avg, har_mean;
}
```

Comment: Another option would be to `return` a `struct`.

Comment: Use a struct instead

Comment: You could also have 2 different functions. This will involve 2 loops but with such a small data set it shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either pointers pr structures.

Using pointer, you can pass pointers of variables to be modified by the callee function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void data_analysis(double* avg_out, double* har_mean_out, double x[]);

int main() {
    //declare variables
    double x[] = { 3.5, 4.8, -4.1, 2.1, 8.4, 6.4, 2.8 };
    double avg, har_mean;

    //determine avg and harmonic mean and display results
    data_analysis(&avg, &har_mean, x);
}

//function
void data_analysis(double* avg_out, double* har_mean_out, double x[]) {
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, sum2 = 0, har_mean = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        sum = sum + x[i];
        sum2 = sum2 + (1.0 / x[i]);
    }
    avg = sum / 7;
    har_mean = 7 * pow(sum2, -1);

    *avg_out = avg;
    *har_mean_out = har_mean;
}
```

Using structures, you can construct one value with multiple values inside that.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

struct data_analysis_result {
    double avg, har_mean;
};

struct data_analysis_result data_analysis(double x[]);

int main() {
    //declare variables
    double x[] = { 3.5, 4.8, -4.1, 2.1, 8.4, 6.4, 2.8 };

    //determine avg and harmonic mean and display results
    data_analysis(x);
}

//function
struct data_analysis_result data_analysis(double x[]) {
    double avg = 0, sum = 0, sum2 = 0, har_mean = 0;
    struct data_analysis_result res;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        sum = sum + x[i];
        sum2 = sum2 + (1.0 / x[i]);
    }
    avg = sum / 7;
    har_mean = 7 * pow(sum2, -1);

    res.avg = avg;
    res.har_mean = har_mean;
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare a struct to achieve that.

```
struct myreturntype{
    double avg;
    double har_mean;
};
```

Change your function definition to

```
struct myreturntype data_analysis(whatever)
```

In the function, you need to

```
struct myreturntype myreturnstruct;
myreturnstruct.avg=avg;
myreturnstruct.har_mean=har_mean;
return myreturnstruct;
```

Comment: `myreturntype data_analysis(whatever)` is invalid in C because you didn't use `typedef`. It should be `struct myreturntype data_analysis(whatever)`.

Comment: @MikeCAT yes. Fixed